# Copy an R data.frame to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel, copy

I have a question which is exactly similar to this [question](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200661037-Copy-pasting-output-from-R-Console-into-Excel).

As part of my work, I have to copy output from the R Studio Console to an excel worksheet in order to make excel graphs. However, the R Studio Console uses formatted text, which excel doesn't read so well. To compensate, I'm always copying from the R Studio Console, pasting into notepad, then copying into Excel. That way, when I paste a table, I can tell excel that it's actually fixed width delimited data, and not just a clump of text.

How can I copy output from the R Studio console so that it goes into the clipboard as unformatted text so that I can paste it directly into Excel and thus organize the numbers into different cells? This would be very helpful as I dislike having to copy/paste tables into notepad then excel to make graphs.

Comment: It might be worth adding your voice to that of the person on the RStudio support site, requesting an additional feature in RStudio.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It works with an easy trick.

First, you have to visualize your data in the Viewer pane of Rstudio (you can use the function `View()`), then you should start selecting from the last value to the first, it is from bottom to top (see image). Note that the first cell should be selected completely. Finally, right click on the selection, copy, and then paste it in Excel as you want, with or without format.

[image]

Good luck!

UPDATE:

based on this [Post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/copying-data-from-excel-to-r-and-back/), other alternative is making a new function to copy your `data.frame`  to Excel through the `clipboard`:

```
write.excel <- function(x,row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,...) {
  write.table(x,"clipboard",sep="\t",row.names=row.names,col.names=col.names,...)
}

write.excel(my.df)
```

and finally Ctr+V in Excel :)

Comment: didnt realize that coping from bottom right to top left is different that coping from top left to bottom right

Comment: any idea why does that happen?

Comment: @user2543622 no idea, maybe it is a bug of Rstudio.

Comment: `View()` was indeed key for me, however, two things: 1) I didn't go bottom-to-top... I just kind of clicked and dragged outside the box until everything was highlighted; 2) I wasn't able to select the column names _and_ the row name header (perhaps because my object is a `data.table` and the row names aren't stored the same). Last caveat of my comment is that I'm on Linux (Mint 17.1) and using LibreOffice.

Comment: The alternative is so much better than the main solution that I think the main should be removed or left as a side note.

Comment: Also note that with this solution the size of the data put in the clipboard is really limited, the answer from @MattV solves this issue thanks to the `max.size` parameter. Finally a note on `dec` parameter, depending on your installation you way want to set it to `,` as Matt did or leave it as is.

Comment: My preferred way is: 1) View(df) 2) Click/Focus with mouse onto the df-explorer 3) press CTRL+A (select all) 4) paste into Excel

Comment: Better version of updated answer below as it changes the size of the clipboard to accommodate a large `data.frame`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30943077/3242130

Comment: `clipr::write_clip(df)` is the only thing that worked for me. From [here](https://datacornering.com/3-ways-how-to-copy-from-r-to-excel-or-from-excel-to-r/)

Comment: I have tried this numerous times, and it has never worked for me.  The clipr method works.

Comment: This seem not work if you're working on Rstudio pro (ie on cloud)?

Answer (score 54):

This is by far the easiest way I have found so far:

```r
clipr::write_clip(my_df)
```

source [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-copy-and-paste-my-table-in-r-to-excel/82540/3)

Comment: The columns' names are shifted when they are too long with `clipr::write_clip`

Answer (score 21):

I usually source the following function:

```
cb <- function(df, sep="\t", dec=",", max.size=(200*1000)){
    # Copy a data.frame to clipboard
    write.table(df, paste0("clipboard-", formatC(max.size, format="f", digits=0)), sep=sep, row.names=FALSE, dec=dec)
  }
```

A few notes:

- Max.size allows you to specify how big the clipboard can become (in kilobytes) before it cancels, it's set to ~200MB right now.
- It works perfectly for copying an R dataframe from an R studio session to Excel (with my EU locale). You might have to adjust the separator / decimal symbols to make it work with US versions.

How to use:

```
df <- mtcars
cb(df)
# Paste in excel as 'values'
```

Comment: does not work for me, unfortunately. Could it be because I have Ubuntu and you have some other OS?

Comment: could be, I'm running Win10

Comment: use dec = "." in the function definition if you're not in EU and want your decimals in period notation.

Comment: It doesn't work : `Error: unexpected string constant in ""mpg"   "cyl""`

Answer (score 8):

From my experience there is no convenient way, I use two methods:

For small data frames, use RStudio's `View(data.frame)` function, if you copy only data without headers it works fine, but if you want to copy with headers then you have to paste it into notepad first to add at least one character to the top left empty cell.

For large data frames, use `write.csv` or `write.xls` (from package [`WriteXLS`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html))