# Save dataframe results into a format appropriate to copy/paste to a word file

Tags: r, r-markdown

Having a dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(variables = c("var 1", "var 2", "var 3", "var 4", 
"var 5", "var 6"), freq = c(202L, 77L, 27L, 19L, 8L, 3L)), .Names = c("variables", 
"freq"), row.names = c(17L, 13L, 9L, 19L, 14L, 10L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

How is it possible to save it in a format like it is printed in the console in order to copy/paste it to a word file? Using markdown?

Comment: You can check wth `capture.output` or use rmarkdown to write it to word document

Comment: Can't you just highlight the data.frame from the console and paste into Word? Or are you looking for something like `writeLines(paste(capture.output(mtcars), sep="\n"), "clipboard")`? (mac and linux use strings other than `"clipboard"`). From there, just highlight in Word and change formatting to fixed-width font.

Comment: If you can get it to Excel, you can copy-paste from there https://stackoverflow.com/q/24704344

Comment: This would probably be considered a Word-answer to an R question but: If you copy your data.frame into clipboard using `clipr::write_clip()`, you can paste it into Word and then use insert- > table -> Convert Text to table

Comment: Take a look at `texreg::screenreg()`.