# How can I transfer a variable in R to Excel?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R called a (2 variables, 2477 entries) and I want to copy and paste it to Excel. I can view the variable, right click, select all, copy, and paste but only a small portion is copied (198). I have tried to use

```
write_xlsx(a,"name")
```

but this only creates a text document. This cannot be complicated and should be able to be done easily. How?

Comment: try `writeClipboard(a)`or `writeClipboard(as.character(a))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy an R data.frame to an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704344/copy-an-r-data-frame-to-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: ... and if you want to export via `write_xlsx` try with `write_xlsx(a,"name.xlsx")`

Comment: @stefan this answered my issue. thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `openxlsx`:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "MySheet")

writeData(wb, sheet="MySheet", x = head(mtcars,10), startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,'test.xlsx')
```